# Table caption very skinny

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table like this:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
Data set & Image size & Hole size (pix) & Total time\\
\hline
Mailbox & 459 $\times$ 489 & 30171 & 1m5s \\
Electric boxes & 688 $\times$ 478 & 45434 & 2m19s\\
Trashcan & 572 $\times$ 517 & 42734 & 1m59s\\
Air conditioners & 400 $\times$ 496 & 13709 & 23s
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{A summary of the data sets shown throughout this paper.}
\label{tab:Timing}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table image]

The problem is that the caption is only about 1 word wide (and centered), so it takes up about 10 lines. Why would this caption not behave like a normal figure caption and simply occur page-width?

Here is a minimal working example (you need this style: daviddoria.com/Uploads/acmtog.cls):

```
\documentclass{acmtog}
\pdfminorversion=5
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
Data set & Image size & Hole size (pix) & Total time\\
\hline
Mailbox & 459 $\times$ 489 & 30171 & 1m5s \\
Electric boxes & 688 $\times$ 478 & 45434 & 2m19s\\
Trashcan & 572 $\times$ 517 & 42734 & 1m59s\\
Air conditioners & 400 $\times$ 496 & 13709 & 23s
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{A summary of the data sets shown throughout this paper.}
\label{tab:Timing}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to turn this into a complete minimal document. Simply pasting your code into an `article` document, for example, does not reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @Jake Ok, I modified the original question to include a minimal document and the document class file necessary.

Comment: `\centering` inside floats like `figure` and `table` is sufficient -- don't use the `center` environment in addition (or instead). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures for details.

Comment: Would you mind changing the title of your question to something like "Table caption very skinny when using ACM ToG documentclass"? That will make it easier for others with the same problem to find the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In [ACM document classes](http://www.acm.org/publications/submissions/latex_style), I think you create tables via the `\tbl` macro.

```
\begin{table}
\tbl{caption}{%                                          
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

See section 4.2 of the [documentation for acmsmall](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/acm-small-v1-2.zip) for example.

Change the table to:

```
\begin{table}
\tbl{A summary of the data sets shown throughout this paper.}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
Data set & Image size & Hole size (pix) & Total time\\
\hline
Mailbox & 459 $\times$ 489 & 30171 & 1m5s \\
Electric boxes & 688 $\times$ 478 & 45434 & 2m19s\\
Trashcan & 572 $\times$ 517 & 42734 & 1m59s\\
Air conditioners & 400 $\times$ 496 & 13709 & 23s
\end{tabular}}
\label{tab:Timing}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! I added the correct syntax for my table to your answer - once it is peer reviewed it should appear.